# How does Latexian's live preview feature work?

Tags: compiling, latexian

In particular, does it use any trick to generate the preview more quickly?

Comment: Nice question! Though I am quite sceptic about the concept of this editor. Apart from that: The operating principle of it is very probabilly not based on TeX, but on some other programming language. So, it is maybe better asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: From [their website](http://tacosw.com/latexian/help/preview/preview.html) website: Preview and Live Preview are designed to allow you to see the results of typesetting quickly. By default, only a single-pass through the typesetter is used, and there is no processing of bibliographies, indices, or glossaries. To produce a final document intended for distribution, you should use Latexian's Export functionality, which includes more advanced features. You can view typesetting results for Preview, Live Preview, and Export in Latexian's Console.

Comment: Thanks. Does it perform a single-pass like any other TeX editor, or do you think it uses some tricks to make the pass faster?